# How can I add up two 2d (pitched) arrays using nested for loops?

Tags: loops, cuda, multidimensional-array

Suppose, I want to add two 2d arrays into a third 2d array.

I am using the following code:

```
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&device_a, &pitch, 2*sizeof(int),2);
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&device_b, &pitch, 2*sizeof(int),2);
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&device_c, &pitch, 2*sizeof(int),2);
```

Please note that I do not want to use these arrays as flattened 1d arrays. I want to use two for loops and put the result in the third array-like the following:

```
__global__ void add(int *dev_a ,int *dev_b,int* dec_c)
{
    for i=0;i<2;i++)
    { 
      for j=0;j<2;j++)
      {
        dev_c[i][j]=dev_a[i][j]+dev_b[i][j];
      }
    }
}
```

How can I do this in CUDA?

What should be the kernel call for using 2d-array look like?

If possible, please explain using code samples.

Comment: Please format the code - indent by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 24):

The short answer is, you can't. The `cudaMallocPitch()`function does exactly what its name implies, it allocates pitched linear memory, where the pitch is chosen to be optimal for the GPU memory controller and texture hardware.

*If* you wanted to use arrays of pointers in the kernel, the kernel code would have to look like this:

```
__global___ void add(int *dev_a[] ,int *dev_b[], int* dec_c[])
{
    for i=0;i<2;i++) { 
      for j=0;j<2;j++) {
        dev_c[i][j]=dev_a[i][j]+dev_b[i][j];
      }
    }
}
```

and then you would need nested `cudaMalloc` calls on the host side to construct the array of pointers and copy it to device memory. For your rather trivial 2x2 example, the code to allocate a single array would look like this:

```
int ** h_a = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
cudaMalloc((void**)&h_a[0], 2*sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void**)&h_a[1], 2*sizeof(int));

int **d_a;
cudaMalloc((void ***)&d_a, 2 * sizeof(int *));
cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, 2*sizeof(int *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Which would leave the allocated device array of pointers in d_a, and you would pass that to your kernel.

For code complexity and performance reasons, you really don't want to do that, using arrays of pointers in CUDA code is both harder *and* slower than the alternative using linear memory.

---

To show what folly using arrays of pointers is in CUDA, here is a complete working example of your sample problem which combines the two ideas above:

```
#include <cstdio>
__global__ void add(int * dev_a[], int * dev_b[], int * dev_c[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            dev_c[i][j]=dev_a[i][j]+dev_b[i][j];
        }
    }
}

inline void GPUassert(cudaError_t code, char * file, int line, bool Abort=true)
{
    if (code != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),file,line);
        if (Abort) exit(code);
    }       
}

#define GPUerrchk(ans) { GPUassert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

int main(void)
{
    const int aa[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
    const int bb[2][2]={{5,6},{7,8}};
    int cc[2][2];

    int ** h_a = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
        GPUerrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&h_a[i], 2*sizeof(int)));
        GPUerrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_a[i], &aa[i][0], 2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    }

    int **d_a;
    GPUerrchk(cudaMalloc((void ***)&d_a, 2 * sizeof(int *)));
    GPUerrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, 2*sizeof(int *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    int ** h_b = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
        GPUerrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&h_b[i], 2*sizeof(int)));
        GPUerrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_b[i], &bb[i][0], 2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    }

    int ** d_b;
    GPUerrchk(cudaMalloc((void ***)&d_b, 2 * sizeof(int *)));
    GPUerrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, 2*sizeof(int *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    int ** h_c = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
        GPUerrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&h_c[i], 2*sizeof(int)));
    }

    int ** d_c;
    GPUerrchk(cudaMalloc((void ***)&d_c, 2 * sizeof(int *)));
    GPUerrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_c, h_c, 2*sizeof(int *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    add<<<1,1>>>(d_a,d_b,d_c);
    GPUerrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());

    for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
        GPUerrchk(cudaMemcpy(&cc[i][0], h_c[i], 2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++) {
            printf("(%d,%d):%d\n",i,j,cc[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return cudaThreadExit();
}
```

I recommend you study it until you understand what it does, and why it is such a poor idea compared to using linear memory.

Comment: Thank You .Yes you are right .Now suppose i do this what should be my kernel call ?one thing i would say i use cudaMalloc((void ***)&d_a, 2 * sizeof(int *)); but it shows error; one more thing for h_a why are u using cuda malloc please explain

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use for loops inside the device. Try this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 800
__global__ void  matrixAdd(float* A, float* B, float* C){

int i = threadIdx.x;
int j = blockIdx.x;
C[N*j+i] = A[N*j+i] + B[N*j+i];
}

int main (void) {
clock_t start = clock();
float a[N][N], b[N][N], c[N][N];
float *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_a, N * N * sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_b, N * N * sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_c, N * N * sizeof(float));

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){    
        a[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        b[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
}

cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, N * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

matrixAdd <<<N,N>>> (dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);
cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, N * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
    printf("[%d, %d ]= %f + %f = %f\n",i,j, a[i][j], b[i][j], c[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

cudaFree(dev_a);
cudaFree(dev_b);
cudaFree(dev_c);

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This works for statically allocated arrays only where the dimensions are known at compile time.  For any sort of dynamic allocation (e.g. `cudaMalloc`, etc.) such as indicated in the question, this will not work.

Comment: By the way you are still flattening the array before passing it to the kernel which is not what the user in question wants.