# cudaMemcpy2D setting values to 0

Tags: cuda

I'm attempting to copy a 2-dimensional array from host to device with cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy2D, but I'm having a problem where it seems to be setting my value to 0.

I'll write the basics of my code in the browser. I know the value I print from the kernel is not 0. Any ideas?

```
__global__ void kernel(float **d_array) {
    printf("%f", d_array[0][0]);
}

void kernelWrapper(int rows, int cols, float **array) {
    float **d_array;
    size_t pitch;
    cudaMallocPitch((void**) &d_array, &pitch, rows*sizeof(float), cols);
    cudaMemcpy2D(d_array, pitch, array, rows*sizeof(float), rows*sizeof(float), cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(d_array);
}
```

For some reason, the kernel keeps printing 0.0000. I know that the first element is not 0 as I tested printing the first element of the host array. What is happening?

EDIT:
I tried this code as well but got invalid pointer errors.

```
cudaMalloc(d_array, rows*sizeof(float*));
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_array[i], cols*sizeof(float));
}
cudaMemcpy(d_array, array, rows*sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Comment: `d_array` is of type `float*` whereas the kernel argument is of type `float**`. Also, copying an array declared as `float**` is not possible with `cudaMemcpy2D` as it is not stored contagiously in the memory.

Comment: Sorry the d_array declaration was a typo. Okay, so how do I copy a float** from CPU to GPU. I tried allocating the memory iteratively, but I was getting invalid pointer errors.

Answer (score 3):

Despite it's name, [cudaMemcpy2D](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g17f3a55e8c9aef5f90b67cdf22851375) does not copy a doubly-subscripted C host array (`**`) to a doubly-subscripted (`**`) device array.  You'll note that it expects single pointers (`*`) to be passed to it, not double pointers (`**`).  `cudaMemcpy2D` is used for copying a flat, strided array, not a 2-dimensional array.  There are 2 dimensions inherent in the concept of strided access, which is where the name comes from.

In general, trying to copy a 2D array from host to device is more complicated than just a single API call.  You are advised to flatten your array so you can reference it with a single pointer (`*`), then the API calls will work.  There are plenty of examples of proper usage of cudaMemcpy2D on SO, just search for them.

Also, you should do [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on all cuda API calls and kernel calls, whenever you are having difficulty with CUDA code.

If you really want to copy a 2D array directly, take a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137218/cuda-2d-array-problem) for a worked example.  It's not trivial.