# Copying structure containing 2d pointer to device

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have a question-related to copying structure containing 2D pointer to the device from the host, my code is as follow

```
struct mymatrix
    {
        matrix m;
        int x;
    };
size_t pitch;

mymatrix m_h[5];
for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
    m_h[i].m = (float**) malloc(4 * sizeof(float*));  
       for (int idx = 0; idx < 4; ++idx)
           {
               m_h[i].m[idx] = (float*)malloc(4 * sizeof(float));
           }
       }
mymatrix *m_hh = (mymatrix*)malloc(5*sizeof(mymatrix));
memcpy(m_hh,m_h,5*sizeof(mymatrix));

for(int i=0 ; i<5 ;i++) 
{
     cudaMallocPitch((void**)&(m_hh[i].m),&pitch,4*sizeof(float),4);
     cudaMemcpy2D(m_hh[i].m, pitch, m_h[i].m, 4*sizeof(float), 4*sizeof(float),4,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
mymatrix *m_d;
cudaMalloc((void**)&m_d,5*sizeof(mymatrix));
cudaMemcpy(m_d,m_hh,5*sizeof(mymatrix),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
distance_calculation_begins<<<1,16>>>(m_d,pitch);
```

**Problem**

With this code I am unable to access 2D pointer elements of the structure, but I can access `x` from that structure in device. e.g. such as I have receive m_d with pointer `mymatrix* m`  if I initialize

```
m[0].m[0][0] = 5;
```

and printing this value such as

```
cuPrintf("The value is %f",m[0].m[0][0]);
```

in the device, I get no output. Means I am unable to use 2D pointer, but if I      try to access

```
 m[0].x = 5;
```

then I am able to print this. I think my initializations are correct, but I am unable to figure out the problem. Help from anyone will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `matrix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the issues that @RobertCrovella noted on your code, also note:

- You are only getting a shallow copy of your structure with the `memcpy` that copies `m_h` to `m_hh`.
- You are assuming that `pitch` is the same in all calls to `cudaMemcpy2D()` (you overwrite the pitch and use only the latest copy at the end). I think that might be safe assumption for now but it could change in the future.
- You are using `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice()` with `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice` to copy to `m_hh`, which is on the host, not the device.

Using many small buffers and tables of pointers is not efficient in CUDA. The small allocations and deallocations can end up taking a lot of time. Also, using tables of pointers cause extra memory transactions because the pointers must be retrieved from memory before they can be used as bases for indexing. So, if you consider a construct such as this:

```
a[10][20][30] = 3
```

The pointer at a[10] must first be retrieved from memory, causing your warp to be put on hold for a long time (up to around 600 cycles on Fermi). Then, the same thing happens for the second pointer, adding another 600 cycles. In addition, these requests are unlikely to be coalesced causing even more memory transactions.

As Robert mentioned, the solution is to flatten your memory structures. I've included an example for this, which you may be able to use as a basis for your program. As you can see, the code is overall much simpler. The part that does become a bit more complex is the index calculations. Also, this approach assumes that your matrixes are all of the same size.

I have added error checking as well. If you had added error checking in your code, you would have found at least a couple of the bugs without any extra effort.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

typedef float* mymatrix;

const int n_matrixes(5);
const int w(4);
const int h(4);


#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

__global__ void test(mymatrix m_d, size_t pitch_floats)
{
  // Print the value at [2][3][4].
  printf("%f ", m_d[3 + (2 * h + 4) * pitch_floats]);
}


int main()
{
  mymatrix m_h;
  gpuErrchk(cudaMallocHost(&m_h, n_matrixes * w * sizeof(float) * h));
  // Set the value at [2][3][4].
  m_h[2 * (w * h) + 3 + 4 * w] = 5.0f;

  // Create a device copy of the matrix.
  mymatrix m_d;
  size_t pitch;
  gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch((void**)&m_d, &pitch, w * sizeof(float), n_matrixes * h));
  gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(m_d, pitch, m_h, w * sizeof(float), w * sizeof(float), n_matrixes * h, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

  test<<<1,1>>>(m_d, pitch / sizeof(float));

  gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `matrix m` class/struct member appears to be some sort of double pointer based on how you are initializing it on the host:

```
    m_h[i].m = (float**) malloc(4 * sizeof(float*));
```

Copying an array of structures with embedded pointers between host and device is somewhat compilicated.  Copying a data structure that is pointed to by a double pointer is also complicated.

For an array of structures with embedded pointers, refer to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault/15435592#15435592).

For copying a 2D array (double pointer, i.e. `**`), refer to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137218/cuda-2d-array-problem).  We don't use `cudaMallocPitch`/`cudaMemcpy2D` to accomplish this.  (Note that `cudaMemcpy2D` takes single pointer `*` arguments, you are passing it double pointer `**` arguments e.g. `m_h[i].m`)

Instead of the above approaches, it's recommended that you *flatten* your data so that it can all be referenced with single pointer referencing, with no embedded pointers.