# Why do malloc() and calloc() not seem work when using CUDA?

Tags: c, cuda, malloc, calloc

The dynamic memory allocation using `malloc()`/`calloc()` seems to be not working properly, when used in CUDA.

As for checking, I wrote the following code using `calloc()`. The array seems to be allocated with required memory and I could also assign some values. But I could see only the garbage values, when I print the matrix elements from the Kernel. I thought it could be a problem with `cudaMemcpy()` but, instead of `**A`, if I put like, `A[5][5]`, the code works perfect.

And the `memset()` usage leads to 'core dumped' error.

Could anyone help in getting along with `malloc()`/`calloc()` with no errors?

```
#include<stdio.h>

__global__ void threads(int* dA)
{
 int gi=threadIdx.x+(blockIdx.x*blockDim.x);
 int gj=threadIdx.y+(blockIdx.y*blockDim.y);

 printf("global Id in X= %d, in Y =%d, E= %d\n", gi,gj,dA[gi*5+gj]);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 int **A, *dA;
 int R=5, C=4;
 int size=R*C*sizeof(int);

 A=(int **)calloc(R, sizeof(int*));

 for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
    A[i]=(int *)calloc(C, sizeof(int));

// memset(A, 0, size);

 for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
   {
   for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
      A[i][j]=i*C+j;
   }

printf(" \n Before \n");
for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
   {
    for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        printf("%d ",A[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
   }

cudaMalloc((int**) &dA, size);
cudaMemcpy(dA, A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

dim3 nblocks(R,C);
dim3 nthreads(1);

threads<<<nblocks, nthreads>>>(dA);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

cudaFree(dA);
free(A);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean that `malloc()/calloc()` does not properly work in CUDA? From the code above (which I haven't tested), it seems that you are trying to copy a double pointer from host to device. The correct way to do this has been posted by talonmies in his answer to [cuda 2D array problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137218/cuda-2d-array-problem).

Comment: @JackOLantern: possible duplicate of the link you provided.

Comment: You're not doing any [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)

Comment: @all: Thank you for your answers. I understood my mistake and now I want to deal with the flattened array while sending them to the Kernels. I've to deal with array of size 200x600 or sort of..! Is it fine to use such a lengthy 1D array in computations?

Comment: Depends on your device memory, If you have enough memory you can use without any problem. I use 512x512x256 flattened into 1d array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code isn't related to the use of `malloc` and `calloc` which are host functions. The problem is that you are not correctly dealing with double pointers and how they are passed to a CUDA kernel. As pointed out by Robert Crovella, a proper error checking would have let you gain a better insight in what was missing by your implementation.

Below there is a working version of your program. It is nothing more than an application of the answer provided by talonmies in [cuda 2D array problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137218/cuda-2d-array-problem).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

inline void GPUassert(cudaError_t code, char * file, int line, bool Abort=true)
{
    if (code != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),file,line);
        if (Abort) exit(code);
    }       
}

#define GPUerrchk(ans) { GPUassert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

__global__ void threads(int* dA[]) {

    int gi=blockIdx.x;
    int gj=blockIdx.y;

    printf("global Id in X= %i, in Y =%i, E= %i\n", gi, gj, dA[gi][gj]);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int **A, *dA;
    int R=5, C=4;
    int size=R*C*sizeof(int);

    A=(int**)calloc(R,sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0; i<R; i++) A[i]=(int*)calloc(C,sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<R; i++) for(int j=0; j<C; j++) A[i][j]=i*C+j;

    printf("Before transfer \n");
    for(int i=0; i<R; i++) { for(int j=0; j<C; j++) { printf("%d ",A[i][j]); } printf("\n"); }
    printf("\n");

    // --- Create an array of R pointers on the host
    int** h_A = (int**)malloc(R*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0; i<R;i++){
        // --- For each array pointer, allocate space for C ints on the device
        GPUerrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&h_A[i], C*sizeof(int)));
        // --- Copy the rows of A from host to device at the address determined by h_A[i]
        GPUerrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A[i], &A[i][0], C*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    }

    // --- Create an array of R pointers on the device
    int **d_A; GPUerrchk(cudaMalloc((void***)&d_A, R*sizeof(int*)));
    // --- Copy the addresses of the rows of the device matrix from host to device
    GPUerrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, R*sizeof(int*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    dim3 nblocks(R,C);
    dim3 nthreads(1);

    printf("After transfer \n");
    threads<<<nblocks, nthreads>>>(d_A);
    GPUerrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    getch();

    return 0;

}
```

As also underlined in [cuda 2D array problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137218/cuda-2d-array-problem), it is always better to flatten the 2D array to 1D to avoid this cumbersome array handling.