# How do I allocate memory and copy 2D arrays between CPU / GPU in CUDA without flattening them?

Tags: memory-management, multidimensional-array, cuda

So I want to allocate 2D arrays and also copy them between the CPU and GPU in CUDA, but I am a total beginner and other online materials are very difficult for me to understand or are incomplete. It is important that I am able to access them as a 2D array in the kernel code as shown below.

Note that height != width for the arrays, that's something that further confuses me if it's possible as I always struggle choosing grid size.

I've considered flattening them, but I really want to get it working this way.

This is how far I've got by my own research.

```
__global__ void myKernel(int *firstArray, int *secondArray, int rows, int columns) {
    int row = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int column = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (row >= rows || column >= columns)
        return;

    // Do something with the arrays like you would on a CPU, like:
    firstArray[row][column] = row * 2;
    secondArray[row[column] = row * 3;  
}


int main() {
    int rows = 300, columns = 200;
    int h_firstArray[rows][columns], h_secondArray[rows][columns];
    int *d_firstArray[rows][columns], *d_secondArray[rows][columns];

    // populate h_ arrays (Can do this bit myself)

    // Allocate memory on device, no idea how to do for 2D arrays.
    // Do memcopies to GPU, no idea how to do for 2D arrays.

    dim3 block(rows,columns);
    dim3 grid (1,1);
    myKernel<<<grid,block>>>(d_firstArray, d_secondArray, rows, columns);

    // Do memcopies back to host, no idea how to do for 2D arrays.

    cudaFree(d_firstArray);
    cudaFree(d_secondArray);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I was asked if the array width will be known at compile time in the problems I would try to solve. You can assume it is as I'm interested primarily in this particular situation as of now.

Comment: the [cuda tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) has a link ("using arrays of pointers...")  explaining how to handle 2D arrays in CUDA.  There are also *many* similar questions that you might look at with a bit of googling or research.  In the example you have given, your array *width* is known at compile-time.  Is that true for the real problems you'd like to solve?  If so, it can be used to considerably simplify the process.

Comment: Thanks for the tag page, I hadn't found it yet. And yes, I did look at other similar questions, some of my solution is actually inspired by the ones I could understand. I wouldn't have got this far without them.
As for the known array width - in this particular situation yes, you may assume it is known when answering the question. I'm primarily interested in this exact situation, how it would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the general case (array dimensions not known until runtime), handling doubly-subscripted access in CUDA device code requires an array of pointers, just as it does in host code.  C and C++ handle each subscript as a pointer dereference, in order to reach the final location in the "2D array".

Double-pointer/doubly-subscripted access in device code in the general case is already covered in the [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6137517/1695960) linked from the [cuda tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info).  There are several drawbacks to this, which are covered in that answer so I won't repeat them here.

However, if the array *width* is known at compile time (array height can be dynamic - i.e. determined at runtime), then we can leverage the compiler and the language typing mechanisms to allow us to circumvent most of the drawbacks.  Your code demonstrates several other incorrect patterns for CUDA and/or C/C++ usage:

1. Passing an item for doubly-subscripted access to a C or C++ function cannot be done with a simple single pointer type like `int *firstarray`
2. Allocating large host arrays via stack-based mechanisms:

   ```
   int h_firstArray[rows][columns], h_secondArray[rows][columns];
   ```

   is often problematic in C and C++.  These are stack based variables and will often run into stack limits if large enough.
3. CUDA threadblocks are limited to 1024 threads total.  Therefore such a threadblock dimension:

   ```
   dim3 block(rows,columns);
   ```

   will not work except for very small sizes of `rows` and `columns` (the product must be less than or equal to 1024).
4. When declaring pointer variables for a device array in CUDA, it is almost never correct to create arrays of pointers:

   ```
   int *d_firstArray[rows][columns], *d_secondArray[rows][columns];
   ```

   nor do we allocate space on the host, then "reallocate" those pointers for device usage.

What follows is a worked example with the above items addressed and demonstrating the aforementioned method where the array width is known at runtime:

```
$ cat t50.cu
#include <stdio.h>

const int array_width = 200;

typedef int my_arr[array_width];

__global__ void myKernel(my_arr *firstArray, my_arr *secondArray, int rows, int columns) {
    int column = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (row >= rows || column >= columns)
        return;

    // Do something with the arrays like you would on a CPU, like:
    firstArray[row][column] = row * 2;
    secondArray[row][column] = row * 3;
}


int main() {
    int rows = 300, columns = array_width;
    my_arr *h_firstArray, *h_secondArray;
    my_arr *d_firstArray, *d_secondArray;
    size_t dsize = rows*columns*sizeof(int);
    h_firstArray = (my_arr *)malloc(dsize);
    h_secondArray = (my_arr *)malloc(dsize);
    // populate h_ arrays
    memset(h_firstArray, 0, dsize);
    memset(h_secondArray, 0, dsize);

    // Allocate memory on device
    cudaMalloc(&d_firstArray, dsize);
    cudaMalloc(&d_secondArray, dsize);
    // Do memcopies to GPU
    cudaMemcpy(d_firstArray, h_firstArray, dsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_secondArray, h_secondArray, dsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 block(32,32);
    dim3 grid ((columns+block.x-1)/block.x,(rows+block.y-1)/block.y);
    myKernel<<<grid,block>>>(d_firstArray, d_secondArray, rows, columns);

    // Do memcopies back to host
    cudaMemcpy(h_firstArray, d_firstArray, dsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(h_secondArray, d_secondArray, dsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    // validate
    if (cudaGetLastError() != cudaSuccess) {printf("cuda error\n"); return -1;}
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        if (h_firstArray[i][j] != i*2) {printf("first mismatch at %d,%d, was: %d, should be: %d\n", i,j,h_firstArray[i][j], i*2); return -1;}
        if (h_secondArray[i][j] != i*3) {printf("second mismatch at %d,%d, was: %d, should be: %d\n", i,j,h_secondArray[i][j], i*3); return -1;}}

    printf("success!\n");


    cudaFree(d_firstArray);
    cudaFree(d_secondArray);

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t50 t50.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t50
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
success!
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

I've reversed the sense of your kernel indexing (x,y) to help with coalesced global memory access.  We see that with this kind of type creation, we can leverage the compiler and the language features to end up with a code that allows for doubly-subscripted access in both host and device code, while otherwise allowing CUDA operations (e.g. `cudaMemcpy`) as if we are dealing with single-pointer (e.g. "flattened") arrays.