# CUDA: argument of type float * is incompatible with parameter of type float (*)[32768]

Tags: cuda

On passing my pointer to point to the array, I am getting the foll error:
argument of type "float *" is incompatible with parameter of type "float (*)[32768]

relevant Snippets of my code are:

```
#define N  32768

__global__ void op(float k_a[][N])
{
 //some operation
}
float *ptr_a=(float*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(float));

float *d_ptr_a;cudaMalloc((void**)&d_ptr_a,N*N*sizeof(float));

cudaMemcpy(d_ptr_a,ptr_a,N*N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

op<<<nblocks,nthreadsperblock>>>(d_ptr_a)
```

Can some tell me whats going wrong? I am a beginner to CUDA.

Comment: The error message is very explicit -- the type you are passing as an argument is not the same as the type the kernel requires.

Comment: I should add, this has nothing to do with CUDA. If you just define a regular `void op(float k_a[][N])` and pass a `float*` argument to it, you get the same (or similar) error message. Clang gives me `error: cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘float (*)[32768]’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void op(float (*)[32768])’`

Comment: And why `k_a` has to be this "odd" thing? Will `float *` not work?

Comment: If i use float*, then I am bit confused on how to access the 2 dimensions of array.

Comment: Have a read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: @CygnusX1: Everyone's life will be much easier if you don't tag this with C (which is why I removed it). Otherwise a certain troll from the C tag will appear from under his bridge and start a flame war in comments about "CUDA is not C", as he has done many times before

Comment: @talonmines: The actual problem in this question is related to the use of C multi-dimentional arrays. I expect C people may have more experience with that than CUDA people. That's why I thought 'c' tag may be beneficial. The link by StoryTeller for example - adds to the discussion but has nothing to do with cuda.

Comment: I fully understand the rationale, but this is the reality we live in. Self censor, or enjoy a flame war every time C and CUDA are mentioned in the same  breath

Comment: Although the answer suggests flattening/simulated 2D access (which is fine), in this particular case where the array width is known at compile time, I think this (what you are trying to express in your kernel prototype) is a perfect way to handle it with a slight modification to the types in use. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050300/how-do-i-allocate-memory-and-copy-2d-arrays-between-cpu-gpu-in-cuda-without-fl/41053215#41053215) outlines a worked example of what I have in mind.

Comment: @RobertCrovella What if the array width was not known at the compile time? How would we handle it in that case?

Comment: In that case I would strongly suggest the flattening approach given in the answer.  It is simplest to implement and avoids pointer chasing.  If you really want to do doubly-subscripted access in the kernel code when the array width is not known at compile time, then the [cuda tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) has a canonical question ("arrays of pointers") handling that case, and there are literally dozens of similar questions here on the CUDA tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we have here is an incorrect use of pointers and arrays. According to the definition of the routine `op` it requires a **pointer to array of length N** of type `float`. On the other hand when it is called a **pointer** to type `float` is provided as an argument, thus resulting in an error message of types not being compatible.

If `op` routine is to tackle with a 2D array of `float` values, it is better to have its argument be a pointer to `float`. In such a case all of the `M` "rows" of the original 2D array, accessed with an index `y`, sit in the memory one after another, in a single line, like that:

```
[row0][row1][row2]...[rowM-1]
```

Every such row contains `N` "columns", accessed by index `x`. To get a value for some pair `(x, y)` we have to produce a global index that will access the 1D array:

```
index = y * N + x;
```

Simple as that.

Comment: "*it requires **array of arrays of length N***" not quite right. It requires a *pointer* to an array of length N, which, as you mention, is probably expected to be followed by other array of the same type, that is it is expected to *point* to the 1st elements of an "*array of arrays of length N*". This reveals a conceptual issue, namely that the function in question (`op()` here) *does **not** know the second dimension*!