# CUDA Vision Studio Trouble with Kernel

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I have a project where I have to create a program in **Visual Studio/CUDA** using GPU Threads and Blocks that contain 2 random Arrays `A` and `B` used for computation before storing the result in a third Array `C` the values based on this equation:

**`C(1,j)=max(A(:,j)+max(B(:,j))`**  *(Note: the ":" operator means for all the lines)*

Here is my **Kernel function**

```
           __global__ void mykernel(int **a, int **b,int **c,const int width)
             {
int col= threadIdx.x;
int tempa=0;
int tempb=0;

for(int k=0;k<width;k++){

    int maxA=a[k][col];

    if  (maxA>tempa){
    tempa=maxA;
    }

    int maxB=b[k][col];

    if  (maxB>tempb){
    tempb=maxB;
    }

    }


c[0][col] =tempa+tempb;
}
```

And my **main**

```
      int main()
       {
const int  dim= 5;
const int rows=5;
const int columns=5;
size_t dsize = rows*columns*sizeof(int);
//Αντίγραφα πινάκων δεδομένων της CPU
int *A[dim][dim];
int *B[dim][dim];
int *C[1][dim];

//Αντίγραφα πινάκων δεδομένων της GPU
int *d_A[dim][dim],*d_B[dim][dim],*d_C[1][dim]; 

//Εξασφάλιση μνήμης για τα αντίγραφα δεδομένων της CPU 
A[dim][dim]= (int *)malloc(dsize); 
B[dim][dim] = (int *)malloc(dsize); 
C[1][dim]= (int *)malloc(dsize);

//Γέμισμα των πινάκων με τυχαίες τιμές μεταξυ 
 for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
   for (int j=0;j<columns;j++){


  *A[i][j]=rand() %5+1;
  *B[i][j]=rand() %5+1;

 }

//Εξασφάλιση μνήμης για τα αντίγραφα δεδομένων της GPU και αντιγραφή δεδομένων CPU προς GPU  
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, dsize);
cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, dsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, dsize);
cudaMemcpy(d_B, B, dsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, dsize);

//Κλήση Kernel συνάρτησης στην GPU με χρήση 5 Threads σε 1 Block

mykernel<<<1,5>>>(d_A,d_B,d_C,dim);

//Αντιγραφή αποτελέσματος στην μνήμη της CPU
cudaMemcpy(C, d_C, dsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

//Εκκαθάριση Μνήμης για CPU και GPU
free(A);
free(B);
free(C);

cudaFree(d_A); cudaFree(d_B); cudaFree(d_C);

while(1){};
return 0;
  }
```

I think I got the algorithm right but in this line I get the following error:

*Line*

```
mykernel<<<1,5>>>(d_A,d_B,d_C,dim);
```

*Error*

```
argument of type "int *(*)[5]" is incompatible with parameter of type "int **"
```

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: P.S:Its my first post so im sorry in advance if i messed up the needed format. --> quite a good format for a first post! ;-)

Comment: @Allan Thanks my friend!Really looking forward to a hint as ive been cracking my brain open for 4 straight hours now!haha

Comment: There is a general lack of understanding of certain C programming concepts evident here.  There are probably on the order of 3-6 different kinds of errors evident in this code that would have to be unravelled in order to arrive at something functional.   In general, you appear to be interested in using a 2D array with CUDA, so reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643682/cuda-using-2d-and-3d-arrays/45644824#45644824) may be beneficial, but it does not directly address all the errors in your code.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code, I recommend using [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and running your code with `cuda-memcheck` (e.g. from the command line).
2. This isn't doing what you think:

   ```
   int *A[dim][dim];
   ```

   this is creating a 2-dimensional array of pointers.  What you want is a pointer to a 2-dimensional array (of `int`).
3. In C, when you define an array, you cannot assign anything to elements at the array dimension:

   ```
   A[dim][dim]= (int *)malloc(dsize);
   ```

   arrays only go up to size of `dim`- 1.  `A[dim][dim]` does not exist and is out-of-range for your array definition.  This appears to be related to your general confusion around using 2D arrays in C or C++.
4. This line is similarly broken (assigning a numerical value to a region associated with an unallocated pointer) and is further evidence of your confusion around 2D arrays in C:

   ```
   *A[i][j]=rand() %5+1;
   ```
5. Your handling of `d_A`, `d_B` and `d_C` are similarly broken.

It's evident that you are wanting to use a 2D array in your CUDA kernel, so the right approach here is to probably pick a method from a set of [canonical examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643682/cuda-using-2d-and-3d-arrays/45644824#45644824).  Since you appear to know the array dimensions at compile time, we'll [leverage that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050300/how-do-i-allocate-memory-and-copy-2d-arrays-between-cpu-gpu-in-cuda-without-fl/41053215#41053215).  Here is a fully worked example showing the mods:

```
$ cat t1344.cu
#include <iostream>
const int dim = 5;
typedef int my_arr[dim];

__global__ void mykernel(my_arr *a, my_arr *b, my_arr *c,const int width)
{
int col= threadIdx.x;
int tempa=0;
int tempb=0;

for(int k=0;k<width;k++){

    int maxA=a[k][col];

    if  (maxA>tempa){
    tempa=maxA;
    }

    int maxB=b[k][col];

    if  (maxB>tempb){
    tempb=maxB;
    }

    }


c[0][col] =tempa+tempb;
}

int main()
       {
const int rows=dim;
const int columns=dim;
size_t dsize = rows*columns*sizeof(int);
//Αντίγραφα πινάκων δεδομένων της CPU;
my_arr *A, *B, *C;

//Αντίγραφα πινάκων δεδομένων της GPU
my_arr *d_A,*d_B,*d_C;

//Εξασφάλιση μνήμης για τα αντίγραφα δεδομένων της CPU
A = (my_arr *)malloc(dsize);
B = (my_arr *)malloc(dsize);
C = (my_arr *)malloc(dsize);

//Γέμισμα των πινάκων με τυχαίες τιμές μεταξυ
 for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
   for (int j=0;j<columns;j++){


  A[i][j]=rand() %5+1;
  B[i][j]=rand() %5+1;

 }

//Εξασφάλιση μνήμης για τα αντίγραφα δεδομένων της GPU και αντιγραφή δεδομένων CPU προς GPU
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, dsize);
cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, dsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, dsize);
cudaMemcpy(d_B, B, dsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, dsize);

//Κλήση Kernel συνάρτησης στην GPU με χρήση 5 Threads σε 1 Block

mykernel<<<1,5>>>(d_A,d_B,d_C,dim);

//Αντιγραφή αποτελέσματος στην μνήμη της CPU
cudaMemcpy(C, d_C, dsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)  std::cout << C[0][i] << std::endl;
//Εκκαθάριση Μνήμης για CPU και GPU
free(A);
free(B);
free(C);

cudaFree(d_A); cudaFree(d_B); cudaFree(d_C);

return 0;
  }
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1344 t1344.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1344
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
9
8
8
9
8
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

I haven't fully verified the results, but they seem plausible to me.

Comment: First of all,I would really like to thank you for taking the time to state all these mistakes and confusions i made.Im starting to see the picture i think.So in the answer you gave i cant really understand how the arrays are supposed to be 2D after you typedef them as int[5] arrays.Or you didnt edit that and i have to pick a method as you said for it?Also another question(im getting tiring i know),the method i used with the rand fuction to give them random values before transferring them to the GPU isnt valid why?(assuming i find a way to treat the 2D needed as 1D some way)

Comment: I created arrays of `int[5]` arrays.  An array of `int[5]` arrays is effectively a 2D array.  A pointer to an `int[5]` item can also be a pointer to multiple `int[5]` items, just as a pointer to a single `int` can also be a pointer to multiple `int`, thus, an array.  There's nothing wrong with your usage of `rand()`.  But when you take that numerical value and assign to a location using a pointer you haven't properly initialized  (`*A[i][j]`), that won't work.  It's illegal, and you wouldn't be guaranteed to get back the value you stored there.